# How to set vertical scrollbar always at the bottom?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to set scrollbar at the bottom for lists
Check this fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/69vpnyu1/53/

```
$(".list").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "fast");
```

It will set correctly but when I add more lists to that, it is not setting at the bottom.
Check this below fiddle link:

http://jsfiddle.net/69vpnyu1/56/

please anybody has a suggestion regarding this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

that is because you have given a height of 200px to `.list` you need to scroll it to end of `ul` inside `.list`, something like this:

```
$(".list").animate({ scrollTop: $(".list ul").height() }, "fast");
```

seems to work.

Comment: Thanks. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

```
function loadchatval(){
    $.post('loadchat.php',function(data){               
        $('#load_chat').html(data); 
        $("#load_chat").animate({ scrollTop: $(document).height() }, "slow");
        return false;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

YOu can do that without Jquery:

```
$(".list").scrollTo(0,$(".list").scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try that way

```
$('.list').scrollTop($('.list')[0].scrollHeight);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just replace your line 
**$(".list").animate({ scrollTop: $(this).height() }, "fast");**
by **$(".list").animate({ scrollTop: $("ul")[0].scrollHeight }, "fast");**